# Python function to add or subtract digits of a number

Tags: python

My problem is that I'm trying to write a function `PlusMinus(num)` which will read the integer being passed, and determine if it's possible to separate the digits of the integer with either a plus or minus sign to form an expression which evaluates to zero.

For example: if `num` is `35132` then it's possible to separate the digits the following way, `3 - 5 + 1 + 3 - 2`, and this expression equals `0`.

The function should return a string of the signs used, so for this example the program should return `"-++-"`. If it's not possible to get the digit expression to equal zero, it should return the string `"not possible"`. If there are multiple ways to get the final expression to equal zero, it should return the one that contains more minus characters. For example: if `num` is `26712` the function should return `"-+--"` and not `"+-+-"`.

Sample Test Cases:

```
Input: 199
Output: not possible 

Input: 26712 
Output: -+--
```

My code:

```
num=int(input())
PlusMinus(num)
def PlusMinus(num):
    s=str(num)
    l=len(s)
    rs=''
    r=0
    if(l<2):
        print("not possible")
    else:
        for i in range(1,l):
            if i<2:
                r=int(s[0])-int(s[1])
                rs='-'
            else:
                if r<=0:
                    r=int(r)+int(s[i])
                    rs+='+'
                else:
                    r=int(r)-int(s[i])
                    rs+='-'
        if(r==0):
            print(rs)
        else:
            print("not possible")
```

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_problem

Answer (score 2):

This is a fun problem. Your code works for the test cases you've outlined in your post, but the logic falls down in some cases. For example, your code naively attempts to add a subtract sign if the current sum is greater than 0, and a plus sign if not. This means that if we try:

```
945
--
```

We get the correct answer, however if we try:

```
459
not possible
```

We get an incorrect answer, as clearly `4 + 5 - 9 = 0`, so we expect to get `+-`.

My approach to the problem would be to use [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) to generate all possible combinations of plus and minus signs, starting with `---...` and ending with `+++...`, and loop through them in order, breaking if we find a solution. This brute force solution is also naive, as with some analysis & heuristics, we could eliminate a fair few solutions, but it does work and will provide the correct answer.

**Code:**

```
import itertools

def PlusMinus(num):
    # make our num into a string
    s=str(num)

    # For each possible operations combination:
    for op in itertools.product('-+', repeat=len(s)-1):
        # If when applied, we make 0
        if apply_ops(s, op) == 0:
            # Return the operations as a string
            return ''.join(op)
    # If we've exhausted all possibilities, it's not possible
    return 'not possible'

# Apply a series of operations op to a string s
def apply_ops(s, op):
    # Set return val to the first digit of s
    rv = int(s[0])

    # For each remaining digit, either increment or decrement according to the
    # operation
    for i, n in enumerate(s[1:]):
        if op[i] == '+':
            rv += int(n)
        else:
            rv -= int(n)
    # Return result
    return rv

num=int(input())
print(PlusMinus(num))
```

**Tests:**

```
945
--
459
+-
26712
-+--
199
not possible
```